# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and viewWillAppear causing Data Source conflicts

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

In my view controller I am calling a method to request data to populate my tableView and handle any notifications at `viewWillAppear` and also with a notification observer for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

This appears to cause problems when I am initially launching the app (not from the background) because my `loadJSON` method gets called twice, causing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to crash as my data is changing.

Anyone have a suggestion on how this is typically handled?

Comment: please share some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can test you loadJSON task is or not is executing before call it.

Or you can cancel privious loadJSON task before perform it.

Answer (score 0):

I use global object to manage data, that I should download from different places.
My object (for example, named DataManager) has notifications, block-callbacks or delegate to notify listeners about data updating.
Also it has method to check his state, for example: isDownloading. If my DataManager more complex class, it has enum for states or many methods for  any aspect.

Now I do not like to use Singleton for implementation of DataManager, I prefer to creating a property in AppDelegate to store instance of the manager inside.